# F5 `show sys version` only shows 3 digit only

Tags: f5

According to https://vuldb.com/?id.147676

> A vulnerability has been found in F5 BIG-IP up to
>   11.6.5/12.1.5/13.1.3.2/14.0.1/15.0.1 (Firewall Software) and classified as problematic.

Only `13.1.3.2` has 4 digits separated by dot in it's version.

When I issue `show sys version` command in one of F5 device, the output shows only 3 digits.

How to find out if this particular device is vulnerable or not?

```
admin@(F5_LB_01)# show sys version

Sys::Version
Main Package
  Product     BIG-IP
  Version     13.1.3
  Build       0.0.6
  Edition     Final

admin@(F5_LB_01)#
```

Is there any commands that can show more details of the software version?

I would like to know if this particular device has higher or lower version than `13.1.3.2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to F5 download resource, 13.1.3 is older than 13.1.3.2

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. Can you please provide reference link for this image? Thanks

Comment: Sure, [link](https://downloads.f5.com/esd/product.jsp?sw=BIG-IP&pro=big-ip_v13.x). You should have an account to access download area.